# Can I use a resistor or do I need a regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have two really nice outside lanterns, originally designed for candles. I want to convert them to LED, with a solar panel, batteries, dusk to dawn switch and LED bar.

I understand the circuit for wiring this together. What I'm not sure of is the connection from the solar panel to the batteries.

- The solar panel is 4.5" x 3.5", 1.5 W, at a max voltage of 13.5 VDC.
- The two batteries are 3.2 V, 300 mAh Li4, wired in series for 6.4 VDC.

My questions are:

1. Can I use a resistor to drop the voltage from the PV panel to batteries or do I need some sort of regulator?
2. If a resistor, what sort of value is recommended?

It has been suggested I use a micro DC-DC converter and convert the 12 V panel voltage to 6 V but I am not sure if that would work with a PV panel or be enough to charge the batteries. If it would make things simpler, I could use four batteries per lamp and increase the battery voltage to 12.8 V. Then I would need to drop the voltage to the LED bar to 3 V.

I hope this is enough info, please ask if more is needed.

Comment: You say the LED bar needs 3V only. Why do you connect the batteries in series?

Comment: you should not charge lithium batteries with a series resistor. You should not charge lithium batteries with a regulator. You should charge lithium batteries with the correct charger IC, and as you have two in series, the correct balance charger IC.

Comment: (Jens) The D to D switch, requires a minimum of 6V to operate. That's why I thought to put the batteries in series.
(Neil_UK) if I changed the batteries to NiMh, could I then use a resister or regulator to charge the batteries.

Comment: @Foster Your question right now seems closer to: *"Is there a battery system and battery **chemistry** that can tolerate a charging design made up of a simple resistor and my solar panel?"* If there is, it's probably NiCd (I know a little bit about these) and maybe NiMH (I know even less about these, so may just be my own ignorance talking here.) It *also* appears you are willing to cut your solar panel's efficiency in half in order to get by with a resistor or a simple charging arrangement. And are you aware that solar panels have highly variable behavior over differing sunlight conditions?

Comment: (jonk) Yeah, been off grid (solar powered) for 40 years. I beginning to think I'm looking at this the wrong way. Would be better to go 12 volt on the batteries (NiCad) and look for a suitable LED arrangement

Comment: I'd suggest you go buy a couple solar powered landscaping lamps that you like the brightness off, hack them apart, and use the guts for your project.  That'll be WAY WAY easier and probably alot better than trying to engineer something.